# Lock down access to Azure VM to specific IP

Tags: azure, hosting, azure-virtual-machine

We're planning to sign up for the Azure VM trial as soon as it comes out of preview. In the meantime however, can someone please clarify the following?

Currently users can access an Azure VM instance using a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC).  Is it possible however to 'lock down' the Azure VM instance so that only a specified IP address can connect via RDC?

This would provide us with some extra security knowing only our fixed office IP could connect to our live data server.  Or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Windows Azure load balancer (through which all traffic is routed) doesn't have any type of IP-whitelist feature. You'd need to implement that in your VM's firewall. If this is a Cloud Service (PaaS), then the firewall rules would be applied to any new instance that's spun up. With IaaS, you'd either apply the rules to each VM or set the rules up initially in a VM that you subsequently use as an image for additional VMs.

**EDIT 7/29/2013** This answer is a bit dated. Virtual Machines now have IP-based endpoint ACL allow/deny lists, currently accessible via PowerShell. You can set up separate IP filtering for each endpoint so, in your case, you could lock down the RDP port specifically. See [this blog post](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/06/03/windows-azure-powershell-june-2013-update-for-iaas-and-paas/) for more information.

Comment: Great, thanks.  It would be IaaS so it's useful to know that we can duplicate the rules for new VM's instances.  When you say 'implement that in your VM's firewall' are you referring to the standard Windows firewall that comes with the VM, or is there an external Azure interface for managing this please?

Comment: Yes, just the standard Windows firewall. :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you may end up getting locked out of the machine. If you change your public IP there is no way to get back in to the OS to change the IP rules. Amazon has this supported outside the machine so you can edit it in the management portal.

Comment: I came here looking for a best-practice recommendation, whether or not to use the VM firewall as a second layer in addition to the ACL. @MagnusAkselvoll's comment about getting locked out helped me decide the answer is not to scope the VM firewall for RDP. So thank you.

Comment: @DavidMakogon now you can create ACL in Azure management portal. See [Manage the ACL on an endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/)